# Users say they cannot see flash videos on my website

Tags: flash, web

The users using my website say they can't see the flash videos on the website, even after downloading the latest version of Adobe flash. **May there be any reason for this ?**

You can check the flash videos here: 
http://www.pdfworkshop.com/videos.php

---------------------------------->> **Edit: More details**

One of the users that the videos do not run for him has Windows operating system & Internet explorer browser. 
I've put a check in the videos page to check if the user has the required flash version installed or not to run the video, but even if that user installs the latest flash version he keeps getting my check message, as in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycafc.png

I guess most or all users facing this problem use Internet explorer too.

Comment: What do they see? A blank space? An error? Do they all have a browser in common or is it ALL your users? I can see them just fine.

Comment: tell them to reinstall flash and i bet it works then

Comment: Your page doesn't diplay the right hand bar or footer for me in IE8, and the links don't work at all.

Comment: @shanethehat: I have checked this now on IE8 ... The page loads very slowly and at the end shows a message asking to install Adobe Flash. When the install is complete it asks again to install it !! Any idea what's wrong with my page ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with all IE users.

Your links have hrefs like this: `href=""` which causes the current page to redirect in IE before your lightbox opens with video.

Change your href from `href=""` to `href="#"`

This will prevent the link navigating away from the current page

**EDIT :**

Brad, after reading your comment below I've found another problem.

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash/split_pdf.swf" width="640" height="498">
<!--<![endif]-->
<div>
<span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color: red;">Flash plugin is required to run the video. Please click the button below<br />to download the plugin, install it, then refresh this page.</span>
<p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

You appear to only be outputting the actual flash content for non IE users.

Comment: I have tried this, and i have asked the user, but he still can't run the videos. I have added more details in my question. Please check it.

Comment: I have just used used the swfobject code as specified in the documentation: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Comment: If you look at your HTML for the site you'll see an embed tag that is permanently commented out using <!-- -->. You need this included if it is IE, so same kind as 'ifs' you have already but without the '!'

Comment: There is a similar code to mine, and it works fine on all IE browsers: http://demos.learnswfobject.com/full-browser/static-exactFit.html